# How to make slidesJS pause after I click button

Tags: slider

I use slidesJS in my homepage.Now I want to click a button to make it pause,but it seems that there is no pause option in slidesJS document.

SlidesJS document:
http://slidesjs.com/

HTML makeup

```
 <!--slider start-->
     <div id="slides">
          <div class="slider">
           <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.fotolovec.cz/foto/albums/Fauna/Ptaci/normal_Brhlik02.jpg" /></a></div>
           <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/34484850.jpg" /></a></div>
          </div>

          <div id="navbar">
             <a id="prev" href="#">Prev</a> 
             <a id="next" href="#">Next</a>
             <a href="#" id="control">Pause</a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!--slider end-->
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function(){
             $('#slides').slides({
                    preload: true,
                    preloadImage: 'loading.gif',
                    play: 2000,
                    pause: 2000,
                    hoverPause: true,
                    autoHeight: true,
                    effect:'slide',
                    container: 'slider'
            });
         });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function sliderPause(){
            clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
            }``
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery.slides.js file do a search for _this.stop(true);

It shows about 3-4 times, next & previous click.. and you will also see it showing for paginationLink.click

The problem i was having was the slider was stop sliding after click either previous, next or pagination. I needed the slider to restart.. so what i did was add a setTimeout to play()

```
_this.stop(true);

setTimeout(function ()
{ _this.play(true) }, 3000);
```